# using C, if statement not working (using fork and child processes to run some part of the program)

Tags: c, bash

i've created a program which is a re-make of the wc program in BASH. For some reason my check doesn't work as it should. Word count and Line count (which are handled by my child processes, using fork) still display when they should not. if i type './test -n' it is only meant to display the current user. however it seems to display that followed by word and line count, even though i didn't ask for it. the if statement which doesn't seem to work is near the bottom of the code. here is my code:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* Size of character buffer to read in a file. */
#define BUFFSIZE 1000000

/* Read file 'filename' into character buffer 'text'.
 *
 * @param filename file to read from
 * @param text     character buffer to read into
 *
 * @return the number of bytes read.
 */

long read_file(char *filename, char *buff)
{
    FILE *fp   = fopen(filename, "r");
    long  size = 0; // Number of characters read.
    int   len  = 0;
    if (fp == NULL) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"1 Error could not open file: %s\n",strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        /* Go to the end of the file. */
        if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) 
        {
                /* Get the size of the file. */
                size = ftell(fp);
                if (size == -1) 
                {
                    fprintf(stderr,"2 Error could not open file: %s\n",strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
                }
                 /* Go back to the start of the file. */
                 if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) 
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr,"3 Error rewinding to start of file: %s\n",strerror(errno));
                        return -1;
                    }
                /* Read the entire file into memory. */
                len = fread(buff, sizeof(char), (size_t)size, fp);
                if (len == 0) 
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr,"4 Error reading file into memory: %s\n",strerror(errno));
                        return -1;
                    }
            else
                {
                    buff[++len] = '\0'; /* Add a null-terminator. */
                }
        }
        (void)fclose(fp);
        return size;
}
int compute_words(char* fileloc)
    {       
        int wordcount = 0;
        int check = 1;
        char file;
        FILE *f = fopen(fileloc, "r");
        while((file=getc(f)) != EOF)
            {   
                if(isspace(file) || file == '\t' || file == '\n')
                {
                    if (check == 0)
                        {
                            check++;
                            wordcount++;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    check = 0;
                }
            }   
        fclose(f);
        return wordcount;
    }
int compute_lines(char* fileloc)
    {
        int linecount = 0;
        char file;
        FILE *f = fopen(fileloc, "r");
        while((file=getc(f)) != EOF)
            {   
                if(file == '\n')
                linecount++;
            }
        fclose(f);
        return linecount;
    }
/* The name of this program. */
const char* program_name;
/* Prints usage information for this program to STREAM (typically
stdout or stderr), and exit the program with EXIT_CODE. Does not
return. */
void print_usage (FILE* stream, int exit_code)
    {
        fprintf (stream, "Usage: %s options [ inputfile .... ]\n", program_name);
        fprintf (stream,
        " -h --help Display this usage information.\n"
        " -n --num Display my student number.\n"
        " -c --chars Print number of characters in FILENAME.\n"
        " -w --words Print number of words in FILENAME.\n"
        " -l --lines Print number of lines in FILENAME.\n"
        " -f --file FILENAME Read from file.\n");
        exit (exit_code);
    }
/* Main program entry point. ARGC contains number of argument list
elements; ARGV is an array of pointers to them. */
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    {           
        int pipes[2][2];
        pid_t child[2];
        int status = 0;
        int i;

        //printf("\nParents Pro ID is %d\n\n", getpid()); 
        char* fileloc = "/usr/share/dict/words";
        char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
        char* buff = &buffer[0];

        int num = 0, chars = 0, words = 0, lines = 0;
        int wordcount = 0;
        int linecount = 0;

        int next_option;
        /* A string listing valid short options letters. */
        const char* const short_options = "hncwlf:";
        /* An array describing valid long options. */
        const struct option long_options[] = {
        { "help", 0, NULL, 'h' },
        { "num", 0, NULL, 'n' },
        { "chars", 0, NULL, 'c' },
        { "words", 0, NULL, 'w' },
        { "lines", 0, NULL, 'l' },
        { "file", 1, NULL, 'f' },
        { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 } /* Required at end of array. */};
        /* The name of the file to receive program output, or NULL for
        standard output. */
        const char* output_filename = NULL;
        /* Remember the name of the program, to incorporate in messages.    
        The name is stored in argv[0]. */
        program_name = argv[0];     
        do 
            {
                next_option = getopt_long (argc, argv, short_options,long_options, NULL);
                switch (next_option)
                    {
                        case 'h': /* -h or --help */
                        /* User has requested usage information. Print it to standard
                        output, and exit with exit code zero (normal termination). */
                        print_usage (stdout, 0);
                        case 'n':
                            num=1;
                        break;
                        case 'c':                   
                            chars=1;
                        break;
                        case 'w': 
                            words=1;
                        break;
                        case 'l': 
                            lines=1;
                        break;
                        case 'f':
                            fileloc = optarg;
                        break;
                        case '?': /* The user specified an invalid option. */
                        /* Print usage information to standard error, and exit with exit
                        code one (indicating abnormal termination). */
                            print_usage (stderr, 1);
                        case -1: /* Done with options. */
                            if(!num && !chars && !words && !lines)
                                chars=1;words=1;lines=1;
                        break;
                        default: /* Something else: unexpected. */
                        abort ();
                    }
            }
            while (next_option != -1);
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {       
                if (pipe(pipes[i]) != 0)
                    {
                        printf("Error pipe %d could not be created\n", i);
                        exit(1);
                    }
                if ((child[i] = fork()) == -1)//create fork
                    {
                        printf("Error fork %d could not be created\n", i);
                        exit(1);
                    }
                else if (child[i] == 0) //fork successful
                    {
                        close(pipes[i][0]);
                        if(words && child[0]) //child 1
                            {
                                int computewords = compute_words(fileloc);
                                write(pipes[0][1], &computewords, sizeof(computewords));
                            }   
                        if(lines && child[1]) //child 2
                            {
                                int computelines = compute_lines(fileloc);
                                write(pipes[1][1], &computelines, sizeof(computelines));
                            }
                        exit(0);
                    }
            }
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                wait(&status);
            }
        if(num)
            {
                char *z=getenv("USER");
                if(z == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
                printf("\nStudent number: 12345 and logged in as %s\n", z);
            }
        if(chars)
            printf("\nNumber of Characters in the file:%s:\t%ld\n", fileloc, read_file(fileloc, buff));
        if(words)
            {
                close(pipes[0][1]);             
                read(pipes[0][0], &wordcount, 50);
                close(pipes[0][0]);
                printf("\nNumber of Words in the file:%s:\t%d\n", fileloc, wordcount);
            }
        if(lines)
            {
                close(pipes[1][1]);             
                read(pipes[1][0], &linecount, 50);
                close(pipes[1][0]);
                printf("\nNumber of Lines in the file:%s:\t%d\n", fileloc, linecount);
            }
        close(pipes[0][0]);
        close(pipes[1][0]);
        close(pipes[0][1]);
        close(pipes[1][1]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't read all the code but: call `fflush` before `fork`-ing. Compile with `-Wall -g`. **Use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: ok not sure what fflush does, and not sure why i need to do that as my files which i create are used in a function which is then called by my child processes. therefore theres no way for fflush to know what file i'm creating before the child processes have ran.

Comment: I assure you that `if` is working perfectly fine: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something else going on here - an `if` statement will work if you're getting the expected arguments.  Try debugging the main program as it appears you have an error in your option parsing.

Consider the following case statement:

```
case -1: /* Done with options. */
    if(!num && !chars && !words && !lines)
        chars=1;words=1;lines=1;
    break;
```

You have an `if` without braces around the assignments.  Just because the statements are on the same line, doesn't mean the parser understands your intent.  Instead it'll be parsed as such:

```
case -1: /* Done with options. */
    if(!num && !chars && !words && !lines)
        chars=1;
    words=1;
    lines=1;
    break;
```

Which certainly will lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. i've been looking at this code for so long, that even the little things are becoming problems now, lucky thing that was the last one! so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(!num && !chars && !words && !lines)
        chars=1;words=1;lines=1;
```

is equivalent to

```
    if(!num && !chars && !words && !lines)
        chars=1;
    words=1;
    lines=1;
```

You need some braces, or to put everything in a single statement like this:

```
    if(!num && !chars && !words && !lines)
        chars=words=lines=1;
```